# How can I get the name of presentingViewController around a UINavigationController in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I have a modal view that can be called from two different `viewControllers`. Let’s call them `MainViewController` and `DetailViewController`. This modal view is also embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

I’m trying to do an if/else statement based off of which `ViewController` triggered the modal to appear.

The code that I currently have in the modal's `ViewController` is:

```
if presentingViewController is DetailTableViewController {

        //Update a current Distance
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
            distance.name = name!
            distance.length = length!
            if let distanceImage = distanceImageView.image {
                distance.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(distanceImage)
            }

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
    } else if presentingViewController is ViewController {

        //Save a new Distance
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
            distance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Distance", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Distance
            distance.name = name!
            distance.length = length!
            if let distanceImage = distanceImageView.image {
                distance.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(distanceImage)
            }

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

It appears though that the result of `presentingViewController` is only returning the `UINavigationController` that it’s embedded in. Is there some way that I can get around that controller and test against the view that segues to the `UINavigationController` in the first place?

I'm working with `iOS 9` and `Swift 2`. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you post the code.How you are setting & getting presentingViewController

Comment: @RohitPradhan Yeah, no problem. I've added the code that I've been trying to use. I also tried using `self.presentingViewController` with no change. As I said, I tried simply printing the `presentingViewController` to the debug area and found that it was returning the UINavigationController that the modal is embedded in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's between specifically only two view controllers you can pass a `Bool` to the destination view controller.

In your firstVC:

```
let destinationVC = DestinationVC() 
// or storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("destinationVC") as! DestinationVC
destinationVC.isDetail = true
showViewController(destinationVC)
```

In your destinationVC, in your `-viewDidLoad`:

```
if isDetail {
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
        distance.name = name!
        distance.length = length!
        if let distanceImage = distanceImageView.image {
            distance.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(distanceImage)
        }

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
} else {
    //Save a new Distance
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
        distance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Distance", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Distance
        distance.name = name!
        distance.length = length!
        if let distanceImage = distanceImageView.image {
            distance.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(distanceImage)
        }

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

and in your secondVC set the bool `isDetail` to false

Comment: It is only two view controllers that I'm dealing with and as of right now I don't believe that will change so this should work. I'll give it a try when I'm back at my workstation. Based on this, I think I see how I could adapt it for more than two as well so I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: I ended up tweaking it so that instead of using `isDetail = true`, I used `destinationVC.viewThatSent = "DetailTableViewController"` and then matched to it with `if viewThatSent == "DetailTableViewController"`. Then I just set the variable as `var viewThatSent:String!` in the modal to catch it. Although I'm only dealing with two views right now, I liked the flexibility of matching strings better. Other than having to be careful to make sure they're exactly the same, is there anything technically wrong with me doing it this way?

Comment: nice. If you're going to pass in strings, another great way you can look at it is to create an enum and pass in case values of the enum; here's a solid resource: http://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/

Comment: I hadn't thought about using enums. That's a good idea too. Thanks for the help! You saved me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are presenting is navigationcontroller. So one can test for navigationcontrollers property i.e viewControllers which will return an array of view controllers i.e either MainViewController and DetailViewController. So here one can use filter operation for array to check the controller one wants to test.As shown below.

```
let controllerList = (presentingViewController as? UINavigationController).viewControllers
let isControllerExsist = controllerList.filter{$0 is MainViewController}
if isControllerExsist.count>0
{
print("isMainViewCntroller")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `prepareForSegue` and populate a field on that view controller you're segueing to (make it a weak var!).  If the view controller you're segueing to is the navigation controller, which it probably is, you'll need to make a custom navigation controller with the var, and then the presentingViewController will be this custom type, and will have the presenting view controller.  Either that or in the navigation controller's `prepareForSegue` populate another var on your modal view.

Comment: You're correct, the view controller I'm segueing to is the navigation controller. This is where I'm running into the issue. You're solution seems to make sense but I'm finding it a bit hard to follow. Is there any chance you could provide an example in code?